# Matching lines with parentheses before double backslashes using regex in AWK

Tags: regex, awk, gawk

I've got an AWK script and I'm trying to check if lines coming into it have an `(` but only if its before `//` or there is no `//` (its C code, so basically seeing if something happens before the comment).

Right now I have

```
if (match($0,/(\()/))
    do stuff
```

and this matches the parentheses just fine, but I can't seem to get it to stop before double backslashes. I've looked around for an answer and tried a few things but I'm clearly doing something wrong.

Adding the following after the `(\()` has been suggested from what I've found but doesn't seem to work: `(?:\/\/)` or `(?=\/\/)` .

I had a good handle on regex about a year and a half ago but I haven't touched it since then and have gotten pretty rusty. So if there's a good site that doesn't spend a long time on the basics but gives good descriptions of what most things do that would be helpful too (found a few tutorials but none are being super helpful yet).

edit: So a sample input would be

```
#define aa (aad|dadfa|adsfas) // This line does a thing
#define bb //This line does a thing (but a different thing)
#define cc (cccc cccc cccc)
```

and I would want to pull

```
aad|dadfa|adsfas
```

from the first line, nothing from the second line, and

```
cccc cccc cccc
```

from the third line.

IMPORTANT: As seen here I just noticed that some of the lines I want to pull from don't have any comments, so it needs to match `(` before `//` and `(` on lines with no `//`.

edit2: Sorry I kinda jumped into the second step with the sample output. From that sample input I really just need to get a true for line 1 and 3 and a false for line 2. I have code that will then extract the text from between the parentheses. So the sample output given is the final output I am looking for, but the part I am having trouble with is selecting which lines to use.

Comment: What do you mean by "seeing if something happens before the comment"?

Comment: What do comments have to do with this? What it really sounds like you want is anything between brackets. Perhaps you would be better off describing your intentions, and not the regex you want to get there.

Comment: I'm using AWK to get the variable and value from a list of defines. Some are easy enough, but some that have multiple values assigned are written rather poorly (I can NOT edit how they are written, just have to work around it) and the only real identifiers are the parentheses. But I don't want to get stuff from past the // because its not part of the definition.

Comment: Sorry I kinda added extra steps here too. I have code that can pull the text from between the parentheses, I just only want to use it on the lines that have parentheses in the actual defines and not in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want:

```
$ awk '{sub(/\/\/.*/,"")} match($0,/\([^)]+\)/){ print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2) }' file
aad|dadfa|adsfas
cccc cccc cccc
```

It just strips any comment from the line and then extracts any text between parens.

If not, try again to clarify your requirements and provide more representative input/output.

Comment: I just realized that it also needs to match ( when there is no // at all, what would need to be changed to make that work?

Comment: If you just need to match any line with a bracket, just do `.*(.*`

Comment: Added some sample input/output, sorry about that. Let me know if its still not clear (I think I'm failing at communicating today).

Comment: I just posted an updated answer, see if it's what you're looking for.

Comment: That does what I'm looking for, thanks. Sorry about the confusion, I'm not thinking clearly today apparently.

Answer (score -1):

regex = `.*\(.*\/\/.*`
tested here:

http://regexr.com/38v3v

To get the full line that matches a ( somewhere followed by a // comment,

`.*` gets the beginning of the line up to the
`(` which is necessary to match, followed by
`.*` the rest of the line up to the
`\/\/` comment indicator, followed by
`.*` the text of the comment

Comment: True. lets delete these comments and clean this up a bit

Comment: Sorry about that, I think I wrote the question a little fast and wasn't clear enough. I edited and added some more information to try and clear things up.